# Laravel: querying encrypted data loop causes DecryptException

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I am trying to fetch a record by Eloquent. There's a problem so

```
Model::where('condiction', '=', $value)
```

is not an answer since the data is encrypted.

So I've though of doing it like so: getting all rows, decrypting them and returning row if there's a check

```
$whatever = '123';
Model::all()->filter(function($record) use ($whatever) {
            if ($record->whatever) {
                if (Crypt::decrypt($record->whatever) == $whatever) {
                    die(dump($record)); //just for test purpose. change to return after problem's resolved
                }
            }
        });
```

Here comes an issue. I keep getting a Decrypt Exception saying

```
Illuminate \ Contracts \ Encryption \ DecryptException
The payload is invalid.
```

I have no clue of how to resolve this issue hence the code seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. There was a problem with $record->whatever since my Model was using Encryptable trait and getting a value was making it decrypted. So it was running decrypt twice